# computing F statistic with user supplied covariance matrix

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

**see edits below**

With package `plm`, I was wondering why the F statistic displayed by `summary()` does not change once I supply a covariance matrix (for robust standard errors). Consider the following code, I do not get a change in the F statistic as calculated by `summary()`. However, F statstic calculated by `waldtest()` changes:

```
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
data("Grunfeld")
gp <- plm(inv ~ value + capital,data=Grunfeld,model="pooling")

# summary() and waldtest() yield  same F statistic [w/o user supplied covariance matrix]
summary(gp)
waldtest(gp, test="F")

# summary() and waldtest() yield different  F statistic [w/ user supplied covariance matrix]
summary(gp, .vcov = plm::vcovHC(gp, "white2"))
waldtest(gp, test="F", vcov=plm::vcovHC(gp, "white2"))
```

Considering [this post about Stata's robust standard erros](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter4/statareg4.htm) and comparing the output for the F statistic w/ and w/o robust standard errors there, I feel like the F statistic should change.

This was with plm 1.4 (then stable release).

**EDIT**: `pwaldtest` in the CRAN release 1.6-4 of `plm` does that and is now incorporated in `summary.plm` thus, simply running one of the following will give the robust F test with adjusted df2 parameter:

```
summary(gp, vcov = plm::vcovHC(gp, "white2"))
pwaldtest(gp, test="F", vcov = plm::vcovHC(gp, "white2"))
```

Here is a good reference for robust inference for practitioners: Cameron/Miller, "A Practitioner's Guide to Cluster-Robust Inference", Journal of Human Resources, Spring 2015, Vol.50, No. 2, pp.317-373. http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/papers.html

Comment: I like this question but think it might be more appropriate for CrossValidated

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72892/heteroscedasticity-consistent-f-test is related. From Wooldridge, Introductory Econometrics (2013), p. 273: "If heteroskedasticity is present, this version of the [F] test is invalid. The heteroskedasticityrobust
version has no simple form, but it can be computed using certain statistical packages." Seems to me like plm should respect the supplied covariance matrix for calculation of the F statistic [which would make it an stackoverflow issue?). However, I feel like plm is not actively developt anymore.

Comment: Btw `gretl` (version  <= 1.10.1) also suffered from this problem. There, it was fixed immediately after I informed the maintainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `plm:::summary.plm` then you see that the first line is: `object$fstatistic <- Ftest(object, test = "F")`. Thus, the `.vcov` argument is not passed on to `plm:::Ftest()` and hence the F-statistic is not affected at all. You could contact the `plm` maintainers and ask that this should either be improved or at least pointed out on the manual page. Currently, `.vcov` is only used for the partial Wald tests of each coefficients, i.e., corresponding to what `lmtest` computes via `coeftest(gp, vcov = vcovHC(gp, "white2"))`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I will let `plm`'s maintainers know.

Comment: For the F test with robust vcov, it seems one needs to adjust the degrees of freedom, This seems to be a good reference:  Cameron/Miller, "A Practitioner's Guide to Cluster-Robust Inference", Journal of Human Resources, Spring 2015, Vol.50, No. 2, pp.317-373. http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/papers.html